# Circuit Diagram Conventions: wiring a MOSFET gate to "CE"?

Tags: mosfet

As can be seen in the "Typical Application" circuit of the first page of [this datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24650.pdf), the gate of an n-type MOSFET (named Q3) has been wired to "CE".

I cannot decide what this means as CE is not a net referred to elsewhere on the diagram. My first thought was "common emitter", but that terminology isn't applicable to MOSFETs, nor would I know what that would imply in this case. Is the diagram indicating the gate should be shorted with the source? Or is something else entirely?

Comment: Charge Enable which is "Active Low".

Answer (score 2):

It stands for "charge enable" (active low), and is an external signal to enable/disable charging.  If you don't want to disable charging you can omit the FET.

From the data sheet:

MPPSET:  Input voltage set point. Use a voltage divider from input source to GND to set voltage on MPPSET to 1.2 V. To disable charge, pull MPPSET below 75 mV.

So the FET gate can be attached to a logic level signal to pull MPPSET below 75mV disabling charge.

Answer (score 1):

Just above the diagram on the data sheet you will see:

- Charge Enable on MPPSET Pin

So "CE" means Charge Enable.
The bar over the top indicates that it is active LOW.